# Print some of list by for in python

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I have 4 lists and I want to print them, but it returns name of list.

```
list1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
list2 = ["a", "b", "c"]
list3 = ["a", "b"]
list4 = ["a"]

for i in range(1,5):
    print(list[i])
```

It shows:

```
list[1]
list[2]
list[3]
list[4]
```

I need, for example `["a", "b", "c", "d"]` for list1.

Comment: It is not like that, you need to have the fundamental understanding of how variables work, for your solution `print(globals()[f'list{i}'])` will work but it is not something you want to do

Answer (score 0):

You could make a list of lists if you want to print them like you are trying to do:

```py
list1 = [
    ["a", "b", "c", "d"],
    ["a", "b", "c"],
    ["a", "b"],
    ["a"]
]

for i in range(len(list1)):
    print(list1[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

Variables don't work that way. If you need a similar kind of approach, you can use a dictionary.

```
dict_ = {
    "list1" : ["a", "b", "c", "d"],
    "list2" : ["a", "b", "c"],
    "list3" : ["a", "b"],
    "list4" : ["a"],
}

for i in range(1, 5):
    print(dict_["list"+str(i)])
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to print them in a loop, you need to put them in a "container" first (the container is noting but a list of its own).

```
list1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
list2 = ["a", "b", "c"]
list3 = ["a", "b"]
list4 = ["a"]

container = [list1, list2, list3, list4]
for list in container:
    print(list)
```